# Row Level Locks in HBase

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hbase, bigdata

I have started using hbase recently, just wanted to check here if anyone came across the scenario which i have been facing right now.

I have a webservice deployed in couple of servers and accessing the HBase to update a field. Now this field update is conditional means i have to read the field from hbase and if its value is "A",then update to "B". If the concurrent update is "C" do not update. But since different servers and concurrent requests, possible that both read existing value as A and one update with B and other with "C".

If there are requests coming concurrently from different servers, then there is no use of thread level locking. Also multiple request from same server.

Is there a way to lock at the HBase level, so that i can aquire the lock at service layer and lock the row and then update it.

There is RowLock in HBase API, but we are using the higher version (1.1.2.3) of hbase where that class is removed.

Appreciate if someone could show a direction!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#checkAndPut(byte[],%20byte[],%20byte[],%20byte[],%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put)

Comment: Thanks for the information Shay. checkAndPut is deprecated in the latest versions of hbase api. So I have used checkAndMutate method as the solution.

Comment: I thought you were using 1.1.2.3. Anyway, I'm glad you got a solution.